# Can anyone identify this shower door rubber gasket?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, rubber

Can anyone identify this rubber seal or recommend an alternative? Its old and mildewed and needs replacing

[image: close up of rubber seal]

[image: Wide view of door, wall & seal]

Comment: Visit a specialty glass dealer — one that caters to the public as opposed to one that is trade only — and ask nicely for their help. You might get a cold shoulder at the first one or two.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching this Pemko Catalog. I think they are the largest manufacturer of weatherstripping, etc.

https://absupply.net/pdf/PemkoFullCatalog2012.pdf

If you find something close, you can get it (or order it) through your local lumber yard. Amazon has some of the most popular styles, sizes, etc. too.